# DIV's background ain't visible around <textarea> placed within

Tags: css

I want a text-area with black background to be within DIV with white background. Text-area should not fill the complete DIV so the DIV's white color is still seen around text-area. DIV itself should occupy only 80% of the screen's width (or browser's tab). The problem is that the DIV's white background ain't seen around text-area.

```
.mydiv {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background: white;
}

.mytextarea {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', cursive;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #2980B9;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the DIV's white background ain't seen around text-area"?

Comment: DIV itself is all white. Text-area within is all black. But Text-area doesn't fill the whole DIV, so the white from DIV must be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;`

```
.mytextarea {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', cursive;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #2980B9;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    outline: 0;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qyxzrobt/)

```css
.mydiv {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.mytextarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', cursive;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #2980B9;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <textarea class="mytextarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I wanted! Dear alireza safian!!! U just solved it and saved me!!! Cool. Big thanx